# String reverse performance in C & C++ using swapping and recursion

Tags: c++, c, performance

I was practising my C & C++ skills and then I decided to do the string reverse problem in using method used in both languages. I wrote a recursive solution and and indexing method.  There are 4 reverse functions here; 2 use strictly C methods to compute, and the other 2 use C++ (STL, String, algorithm) calls.

- Is this a good comparison to see the speed of each method or am I
  missing something?
- Also I want to find out how much memory each
  method uses but I have not figured out how to do that.

```
// C++ reverse string
#include <string> // string
#include <algorithm> // reverse
#include <iostream> // cout

#include <cstring> // std::strcpy
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <sys/time.h> // gettimeofday

inline void swap_characters(char* left, char* right) {
    char temp = *left;
    *left = *right;
    *right = temp;
}

void c_index_reverse(char* input, size_t inputSize) {

    const size_t strSize = inputSize - 1;
    char temp;

    for(int i=0 ; i < inputSize / 2 ; i++) {
        swap_characters(&input[i], &input[strSize - i]);
    }
}

void c_recursive_reverse(char str[], int index, int size)
{
    swap_characters(&str[index], &str[size - index]);

    if (index == size / 2)
        return;

    c_recursive_reverse(str, index + 1, size);
}


void c_plusplus_index_reverse(std::string& input) {

    const size_t strSize = input.length();

    for(int i=0 ; i < strSize / 2 ; i++)
        std::swap(input[i], input[strSize - i - 1]);
}


std::string c_plusplus_recursive_reverse(std::string& input) {

    if(input.length() <= 1) {
        return input;
    }

    std::string tmp = std::string(input.begin() + 1, input.end());
    return c_plusplus_recursive_reverse(tmp) + input[0];
}


double timeit(struct timeval &start, struct timeval &end){
    double delta = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
    return delta;
}

int main() {

    struct timeval start,end;

    // using C++ STL
    std::string temp = "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \ 
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay" \
    "something very weird is another word that includes a longer text to see the delay";
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;

    // using c++ recursive reverse function - 4
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    std::reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    printf("%lf \n",timeit(start, end));


    // use C++ style functions
    // using recersive - 5
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    temp = c_plusplus_recursive_reverse(temp);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    std::cout << temp  << std::endl;
    printf("%lf \n",timeit(start, end));

    // using index reverse - 3
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    c_plusplus_index_reverse(temp);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    printf("%lf \n",timeit(start, end));



    // Now do C style
    char *cStr = new char[temp.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(cStr, temp.c_str());


    // using index - 1
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    c_index_reverse(cStr, temp.length());
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("%s \n", cStr);
    printf("%lf \n",timeit(start, end));


    // using recersive - 2
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    c_recursive_reverse(cStr, 0, temp.length() - 1);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("%s \n", cStr);
    printf("%lf \n",timeit(start, end));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++, pick one. They're not the same thing.

Comment: If you want to time some code, first of all don't include any kind of input/output activity (which you don't so that's good) unless that's what you want to measure. Input and output is usually *very* slow compared to most other code. Secondly, you should really perform the action multiple times, and get an average (and possibly min/max) times, the more times you perform the action, the better the statistical properties will be. Just timing a single function call is useless, especially on pre-emptive multi-tasking systems.

Comment: @Armen B. I am sure that the recusive function should have at most two parameters as for example void c_recursive_reverse( char str[], size_t size);

Comment: @Barry: I included functions that uses only C++ method, and functions that uses only C methods.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Good point, I will run the function multiple times and get an average

Comment: You should pick one language, OTOH, this should better go to code review. Or do you have any specific problem with your code?

Comment: @Olaf: I will ask admins to move it over if SO is not the right location for this, but basically I want to know if the solution I provided for each method is the optimum solution just so I know I can compare correctly. Also in each function you will notice I only use that language specific methods.

Comment: I did, but that is not the correct way here. You should provide a [MCVE]. There is no language C/C++

Comment: @Olaf: I updated the main question to include this sentence to explain what I mean by C/C++.  __There are 4 reverse functions here, 2 use strictly C methods to compute, and the other 2 use C++ (STL, String, algorithm) calls__

Comment: This question belongs on http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Answer (score 0):

Having an inline function `swap_characters()` is making a big job for only three lines of code, creating more pointers when you already have them (although compiler might optimise). Using another indexing var, say `j`, which is decremented until it meets `i` would be more efficient.

```
void c_index_reverse(char* input, size_t inputSize) {

    int j = inputSize - 1;
    char temp;

    for(int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[j];
        input[j--] = temp;
    }
}
```

*"Also I want to find out how much memory each method uses"*. The non-recursive method uses minimal memory, since it only uses pointers and indexers. But the recursive method uses a lot more memory, since every string character (up to half the string length) invokes recursion, so more stack usage. As your string `"something very weird ..."` has about 600 chars, that is a lot of stack usage, and most of the execution time is spent calling, manipulating stack frames, and returning, with very little time spent swapping chars.

Recursion here is a "hiding to nowhere".

Comment: doesn't `j--` t that take the same number of cycles as `inputSize - 1` ?

Comment: You also have `inputSize / 2` in every loop.

Comment: Also, regarding the memory explanation which I understand in theory makes a lot of sense. I was wondering if there is a way to see exact usage, maybe in some number format?

Comment: What's the point when the non-recursive solution is clearly far more efficient anyway? Better to spend your time somehow else.

Comment: So to use the same method on more complicated functions and to get a ratio comparison between the two methods.

Comment: What is a more complicated function than a string reversal, which is a basic trivial operation (but apparently not from the number of SO questions asked)? Are you asking the right question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83482/discussion-between-armen-b-and-weather-vane).

Comment: As `size_t` and `int` have different ranges, a better solution would not use `int j` but `size_t j` along with some minor code changes to prevent `j` from getting a "negative" value.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ recursive function is really bad: using iterators increases the speed and it's cleaner code:

```
void c_plusplus_recursive_reverse(std::string::iterator start, 
    std::string::iterator end) 
{
    if(start >= end) {
        return;
    }

    std::iter_swap(start, end);
    c_plusplus_recursive_swap_reverse(++start, --end);
}
```